# make nodejs call synchronously

Tags: node.js, synchronous

I want the following nodejs to run synchronously an print second console.log command at the last.

I have checked mnay solutions here, please provide me a solution.

```
var request = require('request')
var op=[];
request({ uri: 'http://api.usergrid.com/siddharth1/sandbox/volvos/John' }, function(err, response, body){
    // use body
    //console.log(body);
    var body2 = JSON.parse(body);
         op = body2.entities.map(function(item) {
           return item.name;
         });
         console.log("inside log "+op);

})
console.log("outside log "+op);
```

Comment: Impossible. Use callbacks or promises

Comment: Can you kindly edit my code? I am in a hurry.
If possible any link to an similar exmaple would be great

Comment: If you **MUST** do it, then you can use the `sync-request` npm module - https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request It's API is basically the  as the standard `request` module's, but it works synchronously and you receive the result directly by assignment.

Comment: @VasilDininski OMG that starts a new process for each request :D

Comment: Lol, yeah, but I guess that's the only way to "block" the main node thread and still have something executing in the background :)

Comment: @VasilDininski yeah it's an approach (using `spawnSync`) that I haven't seen yet, I guess it can be applied to a lot of other things as well. Although it might be much better for the OP to just learn how to deal with async code ;D

Comment: I am dealing with async for the first time. I have an code review in few hours :D and am stuck with this async issue :P Going through callback info but as of now it is going over my head lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to solve the wrong problem. You don't want this code to run synchronously, you simply want to run `console.log` *after* the response has been received. This is fairly simple.

```
var request = require('request')
request({ uri: 'http://api.usergrid.com/siddharth1/sandbox/volvos/John' }, function(err, response, body) {
  // use body
  //console.log(body);
  var body2 = JSON.parse(body);
  var op = body2.entities.map(function(item) {
    return item.name;
  });
  console.log("log "+op);
})
```

It is not "Node-like" to force the request to be synchronous and is very bad practice *unless you have a very good reason for doing it (hint: you don't); Node is single-threaded, forcing the request to be synchronous would make the request blocking and you'd lose any benefit of actually using Node. Don't do that.

I'm not sure why you need two console.logs, perhaps you misunderstood what was asked of you.

As for the reason why you can't have a `console.log` *outside* of the call to `request`: The function you pass to `request` is not executed immediately, it is executed at some point in the future, but it will never be immediately. That means any code executed after the call to `request` will always be executed *before* the function you passed to `request` will be.

This is a fundamental pattern of Node: All I/O has this behaviour by default.

In summary: You've either misunderstood the question, or the people asking you the question are purposefully trying to get you to come to the conclusion that what you want is not possible (or, certainly, not recommended)

Comment: Hey Dan thank you for replying. Actually I want that `op` array outside the function, so that I can use that data for comparing with other arrays and doing stuff. 
But with this code, it is not happening. I think I am confused and my question is confusing.

Comment: You can't do that. You won't be able to access the elements of the `op` array outside of that callback because they will not be populated until after the callback is called. What you want is to use a control flow library like `async` or use promises.

Comment: Ok Dan got the point. One last question, how can I add an header in request? I need to pass an authorization header along with the uri.

Comment: Pretty sure `request` accepts a `headers` key in the object you pass to it. I'd advise you read the documentation of the library you are using.